# Which postgresql index types suitable for XML data type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Postgresql has 4 types of index which are btree (default), hash, GIN and GIST. 
Which index type suit most for the following scenarios:

1. search XML document via xpath. for example `((xpath('/book/id/text()', xml))[1]::text)`
2. Full text search over XML document

Comment: For 1) if that is always the same xpath, just create an index on that xpath expression. I am not aware of any index type that will allow arbitrary xpath expression to use an index. JSON/JSONB is more suited for that nowadays

Comment: For 2) FTS uses its own index. Use with caution though, it can be quite large. [PostgreSQL wiki on XML indexing](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Indexing) -- For 1) be aware that [index on xpath expression may give no speed up at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504278/postgresql-index-on-xpath-expression-gives-no-speed-up)

Comment: Pozs, thanks for the explaination. It seems like there is no one-size-fits-all solution when indexing postgresql XML data type. I should consider to convert the xml to json and store it in jsonb column.